# XAMPP- MySQL shutdown with 2696

Tags: mysql, installation, server, xampp

I've been trying for hours, did everything from setting my password to clearing ibdata, checking everywhere for another mysqld server running on another port, but found nothing. Could you help me out,Please?

```
2021-02-16 13:18:39 7808 [Note] InnoDB: `​Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages`​
2021-02-16 13:18:39 7808 [Note] InnoDB: `The InnoDB memory heap is disabled`
2021-02-16 13:18:39 7808 [Note] InnoDB: `Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions`
2021-02-16 13:18:39 7808 [Note] InnoDB:` _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier`
2021-02-16 13:18:39 7808 [Note] InnoDB: `Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11`
2021-02-16 13:18:39 7808 [Note] InnoDB: `Using generic crc32 instructions`
2021-02-16 13:18:39 7808 [Note] InnoDB: `Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M`
2021-02-16 13:18:39 7808 [Note] InnoDB: `Completed initialization of buffer pool`
2021-02-16 13:18:40 7808 [Note] InnoDB: `Highest supported file format is Barracuda.`
2021-02-16 13:18:40 7808 [Note] InnoDB: `128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2021-02-16 13:18:40 7808 [Note] InnoDB: `Waiting for purge to start`
2021-02-16 13:18:40 7808 [Note] InnoDB:  `Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.42-84.2 started; log sequence number 1835247`
2021-02-16 13:18:40 3084 [Note] InnoDB: `Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started`
2021-02-16 13:18:40 7808 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.`
2021-02-16 13:18:40 7808 [Note]` Server socket created on IP: '::'.`
2021-02-16 13:18:40 7808 [ERROR] Can't start server: `Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.`
2021-02-16 13:18:40 7808 [ERROR]` Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?`
2021-02-16 13:18:40 7808 [ERROR]` Aborting`
```

Comment: Applying random solutions will only end up in data corruption. The error is found on the second last line of your logs. You have an existing version installed. Remove that before installing xampp. Include in your question the xampp version. What is 2696?

Comment: 2696 is the error number,mr danblack. I'll try it out. Thanks for your suggestion!